# Google Bigquery streaming (python 3): BadRequest 400 POST No rows present in the request

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I stream my data from AppEngine into Bigquery with this code:

```
errors = client.insert_rows(table, bigquery_rows_to_insert)  # API request()
try:
    assert errors == []
except AssertionError:
    handle_error()
```

But I'm getting a server error **BadRequest 400 POST No rows present in the request.**
Why this error could happen? Why didnt exception catch it?

Comment: Please check if the variable "bigquery_rows_to_insert" has some data/is not empty.

Comment: if there was a schema mismatch in any of the rows in the variable bigquery_rows_to_insert?  The data has any extra spaces?  The bigquery_rows_to_insert has data?